# How to change the color of particular file type in bash shell in linux?

Tags: bash

My problem is that there are several file types in one directory and i don't want to create different directories for each file type.

I have .c files , .cpp files , and .pl files.
Is there any command in bash shell to set particular color to one type of file ?
Like this

.c = blue
.cpp = red
.pl = orange

Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the $LS_COLORS variable. Configure it like this:

```
LS_COLORS='*.c=01;32:*.cpp=31:*.pl=01;35:'
```

You can experiment with the values to get different colours. For reference, see [Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html).